# How to specify the name of an object file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cc

When I intuitively try to run such command

```
cc -c source.c header.h -o a_name_different_than_source.o
```

the following error is thrown

> cc: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files

Comment: Why do you want to compile "header.h"? Including it in source.c is enough.

Comment: To compile a single file program, use `gcc -Wall -g source.c -o binprog` and then use `gdb` to debug `binprog`. For programs with several source files and headers, learn to use a builder like `make` (or `omake`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not put `header.h` in your command line:

```
cc -c source.c -o a_name_different_than_source.o
```

will work.

Comment: I suggest to replace `cc` with `gcc -Wall -g` to get warnings and debugging information and use the GCC compiler. And compiling `source.c` source file into `source.o` object file (to be linked later) is very common. No need to name the object `a_different_name.o`

Answer (score 0):

A .c file does not require you to mention the headers on the command line, GCC takes care of that.

A simple `gcc inputFilename -o outfileName` should suffice.